# Projecting plane onto new coordinate system

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

Say I have a grid

```
xGrid = np.linspace(0.1, 1, 10)
yGrid = np.linspace(5, 10, 5)
```

and some data on that grid:

```
X, Y = np.meshgrid(xGrid, yGrid, indexing='ij')
Z = X*Y + 1
```

I could easily now plot `Z(x, y)`. Now, there is a transformation `t(x, y)`:

```
T = X+1+Y/2
```

and I would like to plot `Z(t(x, y), y)` instead. To do that, I need to project my `Z` data onto the `t(x,y)-y` plane. What'd be the best way of doing that?

Since I ultimately want to plot the data and not do any further work with it, direct methods of doing this in `matplotlib` (but actually drawing onto the correct new coordinates, not just relabeling the ticks) are also accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use interpolation to compute the values in the projection, for example with [`scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline.html):

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.interpolate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

xGrid = np.linspace(0.1, 1, 10)
yGrid = np.linspace(5, 10, 5)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(xGrid, yGrid, indexing='ij')
Z = X * Y + 1
T = X + 1 + Y / 2
# Interpolate values
interp = scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline(xGrid, yGrid, Z)
Zt = interp.ev(T.ravel(), Y.ravel()).reshape(Z.shape)
# Plot
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 10))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(211, projection='3d')
ax1.set_title('Original')
ax1.plot_surface(X, Y, Z)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(212, projection='3d')
ax2.set_title('Projected')
ax2.plot_surface(T, Y, Zt)
fig.tight_layout()
```

Output:

[image: Original and projected plot]

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem you could use `pcolormesh` that can be used for non regular meshes

```
In [8]: import numpy as np 
   ...: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
   ...: from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection, QuadMesh 
   ...: from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle 
   ...:  
   ...: np.random.seed(2018) 
   ...: xGrid = np.linspace(0.1, 1, 10) 
   ...: yGrid = np.linspace(5, 10, 6) 
   ...: X, Y = np.meshgrid(xGrid, yGrid, indexing='ij') 
   ...: Z = X*Y + 1 
   ...: T = X+1+Y/2 
   ...: Zt = T*Y + 1 
   ...: plt.pcolormesh(T, Y, Zt) 
   ...: plt.colorbar()                                                                           
Out[8]: <matplotlib.colorbar.Colorbar at 0x7fda83cd4ef0>
```

that produces

[image]

If the bands are too ugly use `plt.pcolormesh(T, Y, Zt, shading='gouraud')`

[image]